# How to fix TypeError: ExtPay is not a function with Typscript and Webpack Bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I Trying to install ExtPay a payment library of Chrome Extension as link https://github.com/Glench/ExtPay
and I follow instructions until 3.Add ExtPay to background.js and then I got error I think because I use Typescript and Webpack like this

background.ts

```
import "ExtPay"
const extpay = ExtPay("sample-extension")
```

Error TS2552: Cannot find name 'ExtPay'. Did you mean 'extpay'?

and from comment I Try

```
const ExtPay = require("ExtPay")
const extpay = ExtPay("sample-extension")
```

found Error TypeError: ExtPay is not a function

Any Idea?

this is my webpack config

webpack.common.js

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: {
popup: path.resolve('src/popup/popup.tsx'),
options: path.resolve('src/options/options.tsx'),
background: path.resolve('src/background/background.ts'),
contentScript: path.resolve('src/contentScript/contentScript.ts'),
context: path.resolve('src/contentScript/context.ts'),
},
module: {
rules: [
{
test: /.tsx?$/,
use: 'ts-loader',
exclude: /node_modules/,
},
{
test: /.css$/i,
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
{
test: /.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
type: 'asset/resource'
}
]
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
},
plugins: [
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
}),
new CopyPlugin({
patterns: [
{
from: path.resolve('src/static'),
to: path.resolve('dist'),
}
]
}),
...getHtmlPlugins([
'popup',
'options'
]),
],
output: {
filename: '[name].js',
path: path.resolve('dist'),
},
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
chunks(chunk) {
return chunk.name !== 'contentScript' && chunk.name !== 'background' && chunk.name != 'context'
}
},
}
}

function getHtmlPlugins(chunks) {
return chunks.map(chunk => new HtmlPlugin({
title: 'React Extension',
filename: ${chunk}.html,
chunks: [chunk],
}))
}
```

Webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
})
```

Comment: To use `import` you need to use a bundler like webpack, otherwise use importScripts as shown in the page you linked. The error message says there's no such file so you must have placed it in the wrong place or your typescript config is incorrect.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank for your comment I try this but also found error
Its look like it found the file
const ExtPay = require("ExtPay")
const extpay = ExtPay("sample-extension")
found Error TypeError: ExtPay is not a function

Comment: Did you install the library using `npm` command as shown in readme?

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I use npm install --save-dev extpay

Comment: Try a lowercase name in import/require line. Also make sure you import **ExtPay.module.js** not ExtPay.js

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in development for a webpack project (I haven't got as far as deploying yet.)

```
const ep = require('extpay');
ep.default('extension-name-in-extpay-config');
```

e.g. somewhere along the line the initialisation function has been pushed down one level to the module's "default" object, whatever that is.